# Intellij find all test coverage for a class

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage

I found a really nice set of functionality in IntelliJ but it is very manual...

- use Analyze/Analyze backward dependencies on a object to find all the tests that eventually reference that class.
- Create a run configuration using Test Kind "Pattern" and manually enter each of the test classes found into the "Pattern" field.
- Run the test with code coverage
- Navigate to the original class to view it's total test coverage.

This whole process is fairly slow and user intensive, but it could easily be automated with a single "Find test coverage for class" key-press (It would still be pretty slow, but I could go on and do something else).  Does anyone know if this is in a key binding or plug-in I haven't found yet?  It seems like a pretty obviously useful and easy to implement piece of functionality.

If not, can anyone suggest how I might do this with the IDE scripting console or a custom Intention (I've had no success finding really good usable documentation/examples of the IDE scripting console, haven't looked into intentions too much...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following 2 flows/options based on the Windows shortcuts (don't mind the failing stuff, it's just a quick copy-paste for the sake of brevity):

---

**1)** With the cursor placed on your class name:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (Chose test for launch)
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd> (Select all)
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> (Unselect `Create new test...`)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHFIT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> (Execute selected tests)

[image: Option 1]

---

**2)** With the `Group by test/production` option selected in the find window and cursor placed on your class name:

- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (Find usages)
- chose the tests from the list
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHFIT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> (Execute selected tests)

  [image: Option 2]

Comment: Hmm, ctrl-shift-t doesn't find all the tests that reference the class. Some of them that the "Backward dependencies" find might not directly reference the test but they indirectly use it so none of the other tools pick it up.  Also, ctrl+shift+f10 doesn't seem to work on the dependencies window (it would make the process MUCH easier if it did), or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @BillK **1)** CTRL+SHIFT+T opens the list of tests for the class, perhaps I misunderstood what you needed, sorry. However, ALT+F7 finds all references. **2)** CTRL+SHIFT+F10 seems to work on the bottom pane of the dependencies window, after selecting the tests. I'm using IJ Ultimate 2017.3.4.

Comment: If ctrl+shift+f10 works for you it must be my version (we have to stay on 2016.2.4 because later versions don't support some of our requirements), so thank you very much for your help--I'm sure that's the problem.  As an aside, ctrl+shift+t only finds files directly mentioned in the test (I think)--at any rate it misses 3 of mine that the Dependency Viewer finds.  I'm guessing it's because the class isn't directly mentioned in the test--only indirectly used by an otherwise unrelated test.

Comment: @BillK CTRL+SHIFT+T aside, have you tried the second approach with ALT+F7? Does this not find all of them, or is there any issue?

Comment: ALT+F7 finds all direct uses of the class--I guess I'm having trouble describing what I'm after, sorry.  I want all tests that might add coverage to the class I'm testing (many of our tests are written as functional tests, not unit tests).  For instance, If class X instantiates class Y (the class I'm evaluating) then I'd like any class X tests to be included, even if those tests don't directly include, use or even mention class Y.  This is what the "Analyze Backwards Dependencies" finds but nothing else does.